How can I deal with passing 360 degrees when I linearly interpolate between two headings?
A part of my python program linearly interpolates between two compass headings. It works fine as long as I don't have to deal with passing through North.  Is there a good way to deal with this rather simplistic interpolation?  For example, the midpoint between 340 and 010 should be 355 and not 175. Thanks in advance.
I'm using numpy.interp(x, xp, fp) and it usually works. Sometimes however, I get a 180 degree error such as the interpolation between heading 340 and 010.

Did you try to use 370 instead of 10 ?

How do you distinguish the situation that (1) the midpoint between 340 and 10 should be 355 (thus going through North) and (2) the midpoint between 340 and 10 should be 175 (thus not going through North)? There must be a way to distinguish both cases, or otherwise the interpolation between 340 and 10 would be ambiguous (allowing both interpretations).

@MafMal. Thanks for the idea, unfortunately the data is rather random and multiple posibilities exist (turning right or left).  Most of the time, simple interpolation works. I was hoping that there was a method out there that addressed the issue and I wouldn't have to code all the possibilities separately (adding 360 degrees, absolute value of the difference between the angles, etc).

This is a common issue for calculation with angles, and the most common method to fix is to add a dimension. In this case, we replace each angle with a vector if its sine and cosine.
theta = np.array([340, 10])
theta = theta * np.pi / 180  #radians
theta_2d = np.array([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)])
avg = np.arctan2(*theta_2d.mean(1)) 
print((avg * 180 / np.pi) % 360)  # back to degrees, on the interval [0, 360)

355.0

There is a special case in this method that the average of angles exactly 180 degrees apart will be undefined: arctan2(0, 0) doesn't have an answer - but then, it was kinda undefined before, as there's two valid answers.  If necessary that edge case can be handled, but more information on how it needs to be handled would need to come from you.
This can be expanded to np.interp (average is just interp at .5) but without test code it's a bit hard to see exactly how the implementation might come together in your case.
